# Firebase / Facebook - How to Log Off / Sign Off?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am stuck in a loop here.

- Users can log in with their FB account. The app creates a Firebase user w/ the same info.
- With the launcher activity (LoginActivity), if it detects an user is already logged in, it redirects them to their profile fragment.
- However, on the profile fragment, I click the log off button and redirect
  them to the Login page. This is where the cycle begins.
- From code snippets and official Firebase doc, I am using .unauth();. However, my logcat still shows the user is logged in. I've also tried using the Facebook SDK method of LoginManager, but that hasn't worked either.

**LogOut method (in MainFrag)**

```
public void LogOut(){

    Log.d(TAG, "CHECK #2: USER SIGNED OUT");

    getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra("user_id");
    getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra("profile_picture");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "signed out" + mUser.getUid());
  //  mAuth.unauth();
Intent intent = new    Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),       
LoginActivity.class);

    myFirebaseRef.unauth();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "CHECK 3: FINISIHED SIGNED OUT");

    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidBash";
    public User user;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    //Add YOUR Firebase Reference URL instead of the following URL
    private Firebase mRef=new Firebase("https://fitmaker-ee2c0.firebaseio.com/");

    //FaceBook callbackManager
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    //

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (mUser != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "CHECK - FB SIGN IN - USER IS LOGGED IN " + mUser.getUid());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomColorActivity.class);
            String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            String image=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();
            intent.putExtra("user_id", uid);
            if(image!=null || image!=""){
                intent.putExtra("profile_picture",image);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());
        }

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (mUser != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };

        //FaceBook
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                signInWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            }
        });
        //

   }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email_id);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


    //FaceBook
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    //

    protected void setUpUser() {
        user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
    }

    public void onSignUpClicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onLoginClicked(View view) {
        setUpUser();
        signIn(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    }

    private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            intent.putExtra("user_id", uid);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
        //
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
            email.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
        }

        String userPassword = password.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
            password.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }


    private void signInWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithFacebook:" + token.getToken());

        showProgressDialog();


        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            String uid=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            String name=task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName();
                            String email=task.getResult().getUser().getEmail();
                            String image=task.getResult().getUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();

                             //Create a new User and Save it in Firebase database
                            User user = new User(uid,name,null,email,name);
                            user = new User();
                           // user.setId(authData.getUid());
                            user.setName(name);
                            user.setEmail(email);
                            user.saveUser();

                           // mRef.child("uid").setValue(uid);
                           // mRef.child(name).setValue(user);

                            Log.d(TAG, uid);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomColorActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user_id",uid);
                            intent.putExtra("profile_picture",image);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
    }


    public void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }


    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "AndroidBash";
public User user;


private Firebase myFirebaseRef =new Firebase("https://fitmaker-ee2c0.firebaseio.com/");

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


private TextView name;
private TextView welcomeText;
private Button changeButton;
private Button revertButton;
private Button FBButton;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
// To hold Facebook profile picture
private ImageView profilePicture;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //Add YOUR Firebase Reference URL instead of the following URL
    myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fitmaker-ee2c0.firebaseio.com/");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
    welcomeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_welcome);
    changeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_change);
    revertButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_revert);
    FBButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_fb);

    profilePicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

    //Get the uid for the currently logged in User from intent data passed to this activity
    String uid = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_id");
    //Get the imageUrl  for the currently logged in User from intent data passed to this activity
    String imageUrl = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_picture");
    Log.d(TAG, "MainFrag - OnCreateView Check");


    new ImageLoadTask(imageUrl, profilePicture).execute();

    //Referring to the name of the User who has logged in currently and adding a valueChangeListener
    myFirebaseRef.child(uid).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //onDataChange is called every time the name of the User changes in your Firebase Database
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Inside onDataChange we can get the data as an Object from the dataSnapshot
            //getValue returns an Object. We can specify the type by passing the type expected as a parameter
            String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            name.setText("Hello " + data + ", ");
        }

        //onCancelled is called in case of any error
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "" + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //A firebase reference to the welcomeText can be created in following ways :
    // You can use this :
    //Firebase myAnotherFirebaseRefForWelcomeText=new Firebase("https://androidbashfirebaseupdat-bd094.firebaseio.com/welcomeText");*/
    //OR as shown below
    myFirebaseRef.child("welcomeText").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //onDataChange is called every time the data changes in your Firebase Database
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Inside onDataChange we can get the data as an Object from the dataSnapshot
            //getValue returns an Object. We can specify the type by passing the type expected as a parameter
            String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            welcomeText.setText(data);
        }

        //onCancelled is called in case of any error
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "" + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //onClicking changeButton the value of the welcomeText in the Firebase database gets changed
    changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myFirebaseRef.child("welcomeText").setValue("Android App Development @ AndroidBash");
        }
    });

    FBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // log user out
            // add choice dialog later
LogOut();
        }
    });


    //onClicking revertButton the value of the welcomeText in the Firebase database gets changed
    revertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myFirebaseRef.child("welcomeText").setValue("Welcome to Learning @ AndroidBash");
        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume of MainFragment");
CheckIfLoggedOut();;

    super.onResume();
}


public void CheckIfLoggedOut() {
    // here, check if user still logged in.
    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    if (mUser != null) {
        // User is signed in
        Log.d(TAG, "MainFrag - Signed In (onResume)");


    } else {
        // User is signed out
        Log.d(TAG, "check resume: starting log out for " +  mUser.getUid());
        LogOut();
    }
}



public void LogOut(){

    Log.d(TAG, "CHECK #2: USER SIGNED OUT");

    getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra("user_id");
    getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra("profile_picture");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "signed out" + mUser.getUid());
  //  mAuth.unauth();
Intent intent = new    Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),       
LoginActivity.class);

    myFirebaseRef.unauth();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "CHECK 3: FINISIHED SIGNED OUT");

    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
}


public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}


public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: check this link::  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJsuB4GpqreTUw1bTBsZU9DMFU

Answer (score 1):

```
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Adding this piece of line solved my problem.