# Firebase is not saving Facebook user in Auth list

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a single Activity for Facebook Login integrated with Firebase.

I have actived the Facebook login in Firebase, followed all firebase steps and all Facebook steps in Facebook Developer Console also.

My Activity has a com.facebook.widget.LoginButton and after click this button Facebook login page appears and I am able to enter credentials, autorize app and login.

But, when I enter again in App, Login Button appear and Facebook login is not saved (cached).

Firebase Auth user list is not being saved too.

What could be wrong.

My code below.

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mFirebaseUtils = new FirebaseUtils();
    mFirebaseUtils.setFirebase();

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class strictModeClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode");
        Class strictModeThreadPolicyClass = Class
                .forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy");
        Object laxPolicy = strictModeThreadPolicyClass.getField("LAX").get(
                null);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Method method_setThreadPolicy = strictModeClass.getMethod(
                "setThreadPolicy", strictModeThreadPolicyClass);
        method_setThreadPolicy.invoke(null, laxPolicy);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // View Pager
    initData();

    mAuth = mFirebaseUtils.mAuth;
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };


    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFacebook);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");


        }

        @Override
        public void onError (FacebookException error){
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);

        }
    });
}


private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    //showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    //hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}


public void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}


public String getAndroidVersion() {
    String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    return "Android SDK: " + sdkVersion + " (" + release +")";
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        //case R.id.button_facebook_signout:
        //    signOut();
        //    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are checking if the user is signed-in. The [recommend method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) is to use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener).  Note that it fires not only when the user signs in or out, but also right after the listener is registered.  You have one, but it only logs debug messages.

This code is not reliable because the instance of `FirebaseAuth` may not have finished initializing:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser(); // not reliable
}
```

This is highlighted in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> Note: getCurrentUser might also return null because the auth object
>   has not finished initializing. If you use a listener to keep track of
>   the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same thing this week and I'm comparing your code to mine. In the OnCreate, I believe you are missing

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

also, make sure you declare

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

. You can see my [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860136/firebase-facebook-how-to-log-off-sign-off)

The app-level Gradle is also very important. It caused me a lot of issues. Make sure you have

```
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
```

You don't need the Facebook SDK because it is already included in the FireBase UI. If you keep it, it may cause some issues. Also, put

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

under the closing bracket of dependencies.